# Can mounting an ISO image execute malicious software within the mounted ISO image?

Tags: windows, mount, iso-image, malware

I use *MagicISO Virtual CD/DVD Manager* to mount ISO images. What I'm wondering is: can a file within the ISO image be executed when the ISO image is mounted by MagicISO?

Comment: Secunia has no record of any known vulnerabilities in MagicISO software.  That's not conclusive, of course, but it's a good start.  See http://secunia.com/advisories/vendor/3356/

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that is possible.

But you need to enable autoplay in windows. This is disabled by default (and for a good reason).  Now if you have an old version of windows which still had auto play on by default and you never fixed that then it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

A file should not be able to execute until something executes in. In windows this should either be done via user input or Via Autoplay (here is the security flaw). Turn off autoplay and you will be safe. It is really never a good idea to have autoplay enabled from a security standpoint.

Comment: Or by vulnerabilities in the Shell or extensions if you open it in Explorer